# Java Regex match all occurrences of a variable after it has been declared

Tags: java, regex

I'm writing a syntax highlighter in Java. I declare variables in my home-brewed language with the keyword var:

> var alpha

Variable names are constructed of alphabetic letters only. Declaration always occurs at the top of the function. I want to match all occurrences of the word after it has been declared. I've got as far as:

```
\\bvar\\s+([a-zA-Z]+)\\b(?:.*?(\\1)\\b)*
```

(The backslashes are all escaped in the Java code)

However this only matches the first and last occurrence of the variable. I've tried to change the '*' to greedy / non-greedy / possessive but it doesn't seem to help.

**Examples:**

> alpha var alpha alpha alpha

all alpha's except the first one matched

> var alpha beta alpha

all alpha's matched beta not matched

Comment: `highlights the first and last occurrence` Regex don't highlight. Are you showing all the information?

Comment: just a comment: it is not good practice to search for a variable by its name surronded with blanks. you might miss cases where operators are attached (like `alpha=1`) or cases where the name is part of a String literal or comment (like `beta = "this is not alpha "`)

Comment: An fyi. All engines overwrite the capture buffers when matching a quantified cluster. I.e. `'abc' =~ ([abc])*` where capture group 1 contains `c`

Comment: `the word after it has been declared` For example `var alpha\nalpha = 22\nvar beta\nbeta = alpha\nvar theta\ntheta = beta * alpha` this will be problematic using a single pass regex. Even to do in multiple passes require knowledge of where the position of the first declaration is. Otherwise, you will match the same thing over and over again.

Comment: The only real way to do it its to either parse it word by word, maintaining a list of `var's` as you go, checking the list against the word. Or do the same thing but split all the words out first, then reconstruct with the highlighted words.

Comment: Another comment, if you're creating your own language, you must have some kind of rule, a grammar. Usually people utilize some grammar parser or semantic or lexical analyzer for your language. It is used for parsing the language, creating instruction chains or simply an editor. One good old parser like javacc should be very useful.

Comment: sorry, im using the results to change the font colour - should read 'match' not 'highlight'. Ill edit that

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if you match the first var name occurences one by one. To ensure that the var names are preceded with the keyword `var`, you need to use the `\G` feature that is an anchor for the position after the last match (this ensures that matches are contiguous).

```
(?m)(\\G(?!\\A)|\\W*(?>\\w+\\W+)*?\\bvar[^\\S\\n]+)(\\w++)([^\\S\\n]*(?>\\w+[^\\S\\n]+)*?)(?=\\2|$)
```

with `$1*$2*$3` as replacement.

[demo](http://fiddle.re/g8nrw6) (click the green Java button)

pattern details:

```
(?m) # switch on the multiline mode
( # capture group 1
    \\G(?!\\A) # contiguous to the previous match (*)
  |
    \\W*(?>\\w+\\W+)*? # to reach quickly the "var" keyword
    \\bvar 
    [^\\S\\n]+ # whitespaces except newlines
)
(\\w++) # capture group 2: first var name
([^\\S\\n]*(?>\\w+[^\\S\\n]+)*?) # capture group 3:
                         # reach the next occurence of the var name
                         # or the end of the line
(?=\\2|$)
```

(*) before the first result `\G` matches the start of the string by default. `(?!\\A)` is only here to prevent this case.

Comment: newlines are acceptable after the declaration, to catch the variable name in the rest of the document (spanning multiple lines, all in one string)

Comment: also this doesn't seem to work - it catches any words after the declaration, not just the one that is declared?